# How to show a warning window before opening a combobox items list?

Tags: wpf, combobox, popup

My requirement is to show a warning window (in some specific conditions) when clicking on a WPF combobox, just before it shows a list of available items to choose from. The window asks the user if he proceeds or not.

The problem is that after showing this warning window, the combobox popup that should appear to select an item is not open, no matter if I set the property IsDropDownOpen to do so. See the code for details.

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxTester.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox Height="20" PreviewMouseDown="ComboBox_PreviewMouseDown">
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <CheckBox x:Name="warningConditionCheckBox" >Is warning condition?</CheckBox>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and the code behind contains:

```
namespace ComboBoxTester {
using System.Windows.Input;

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ComboBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (warningConditionCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
        {
            // Warn about this situation
            var window = new MyDialog { Owner = GetWindow(this) };

            // Confirm to proceed
            if (window.ShowDialog() != true) {
                e.Handled = true;
            } 
            else {
                comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

MyDialog is just a Dialog Window:

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxTester.MyDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MyDialog" Height="150" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Background="Silver">
        <TextBlock Text="Warning! Sure to proceed?" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <Button Width="100" Content="OK" IsDefault="True" Click="ButtonOkClick"/>
        <Button Width="100" Content="Cancel" IsCancel="True"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```
namespace ComboBoxTester {
using System.Windows;

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MyDialog.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MyDialog
{
    public MyDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonOkClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = true;
    }
}
}
```

My idea is to use the WPF combobox to deal with this requirement. And to not create another control, if this is possible. So... How can I see the list of items from this combobox after showing a window? Any suggestion helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often an issue in WPF that while you are in an event handler you can set other UI controls' properties but they are not processed properly.

But you can invoke your change via the dispatcher, which will queue your request in the UI Message Queue, where it is properly processed after your event handler:

Instead of

```
  comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
```

use:

```
  Action action = () => comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
  Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
```